# Solidity Smartcontract Whitelist up to 1000 wallets at once

Tags: polygon, solidity, smartcontracts, whitelist

**Hello!**

I want to whitelist 1000 wallets every month or so. I can add wallets to whitelist with smartcontarct one by one but it takes so much time. Is there a faster way?

```
mapping(address => bool) public addresses;

    function whitelistAddresses(address[] _addresses) onlyOwner {
        require(!whitelistInitialized);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _addresses.length; i++) {
            addresses[_addresses[i]] = true;
        }
```

Like, It would be easier to prepare this kind of data to add whitelist every month but how can I do it?

```
    [{
   "address": "0x123",
   "state": true
   },
   {
   "address: "0x234",
   "state": false
   }]
```

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I am posting this "answer", i think a solution could be a merkle tree, you could generate a merkle tree of address, is on you to decide if you want to store it on chain or off chain, here an example https://github.com/miguelmota/merkletreejs-solidity